# JavaFX - how to edit/use variables in scenes

Tags: java, javafx, dependencies, fxml

How do I change the value of a label in a JavaFX Scene? I'm trying to figure out a way to change the label's textual value on button click, but it's not working.
I've set up an **fx:id** for the button and label and set their controller (**CPCS305_JAVAFX_FXML**, the class itself. The button is also linked to the **handleButtonAction2()** function.

```
public class CPCS305_JAVAFX_FXML extends Application {

@FXML
Scene scene;
Stage stage;
Label main_label
Button login_button;
AnchorPane root;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction2(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, Exception {
    main_label.setText("Hello World");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}
```

The error report is this:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 45 moreCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at cpcs305_javafx_fxml.CPCS305_JAVAFX_FXML.handleButtonAction2(CPCS305_JAVAFX_FXML.java:64)
... 55 more
```

I have 2 other FXML files with their controllers, functions, but I'm leaving that for later. I'd like to solve the problem of not being able to communicate in one scene, then move on to multiple scenes.

Any ideas for the new learner?

EDIT: FXML File for this class
http://textuploader.com/d4wgi

EDIT2: FIXED. PROBLEM WAS WITH WRONG IMPORTS. Sorry for the trouble everyone, but thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to annotate *each instance field* with @FXML in order to have it assigned by the FXML Loader. Without doing so the values will remain `null`. Also, the FXML loader needs to know which object is the controller. You have specified that in the FXML by `fx:controller="cpcs305_javafx_fxml.CPCS305_JAVAFX_FXML"`, but that will mean that the `FXMLLoader` will create a second instance of your class as it does have a way to connect it to your current class. You do this by either specifying a controller with `setController`, a controller factory by `setControllerFactory`, or by passing the arguments in one of the more argument taking static functions.

As you have defined the class in the FXML you need to use a controller factory. The FXML loader will ask the controller factory to instantiate an object of the class it gives as an argument. As you want to use your already instantiated class just simply ignore the class argument and return `this`.

```
public class CPCS305_JAVAFX_FXML extends Application {
    @FXML // because there is a fx:id="main_label"  in the FXML
    private Label main_label;  // Java naming convention would be mainLabel

    @FXML // because there is a fx:id="login_button"  in the FXML
    private Button login_button; // Java naming convention would be loginButton

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
       FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
       loader.setControllerFactory(controllerClass -> this); // 'this' object will be the controller.
       Parent root = loader.load();
       Scene scene = new Scene(root);
       stage.setScene(scene);
       stage.show();
    }

   @FXML // because there is a onAction="#handleButtonAction" in the FXML
   private void handleButtonAction() { // parameter is optional
      main_label.setText("Hello World");
   }
}
```

Comment: I followed your steps and did what you've suggested, but it still doesn't work. It doesn't run now, and it says in two lines of the error report: 
"Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method" 
and 
"Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane cannot be cast to javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader"

Answer (score 0):

The @FXML annotation should be on top of only elements defined in your FXML file like your label, button, and anchorpane.

Try it out let's see.

Comment: I tried taking out Scene, Stage from @FXML and defined them on top, as suggested, but it resulted in an "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException".

Answer (score 0):

I had used wrong imports for the button/label I was using on Scene Builder. I fixed those imports and everything worked.